# List of data in Flutter is not showing

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart

I have a list of quotes (three quotes) and am using the map function to map through the list of quotes to create a small widget for each one. But the quotes doesn't display on the app.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: QuoteList(),
  ));
}

class QuoteList extends StatefulWidget {
  const QuoteList({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<QuoteList> createState() => _QuoteListState();
}

class _QuoteListState extends State<QuoteList> {

  List<String> quotes = [
    "There are three constants in life.. change, choice and principles.",
    "In three words I can sum up everything Ive learned about life: it goes on.",
    "Guests, like fish, begin to smell after three days."
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Awesome Quotes'),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: quotes.map((e) => Text(e)).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: try moving the `quotes` initialization into the `build` method.

Comment: your code works for me

Comment: Tried it on DartPad - it works on my end.

Comment: @LukaCerrutti  it worked when moved to the build method. Thank you. But a bit confuse why it works for others.

Comment: They might have only tried the dart's logic on dart pad or something. The fact of where you initialize your variables in flutter actually `matters`. Also I would personally try if using `final` declaration outside the `build` method works (as this might be the best solution if it does work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the quotes variable initialization inside the `build` method.

```
class _QuoteListState extends State<QuoteList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var quotes = [
      "There are three constants in life.. change, choice and principles.",
      "In three words I can sum up everything Ive learned about life: it goes on.",
      "Guests, like fish, begin to smell after three days."
    ];

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Awesome Quotes'),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: quotes.map((e) => Text(e)).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Also you can use type inference and use `var` instead of clarifying `List<String>`.

Answer (score 0):

Works perfect on DartPad.

Try to run "flutter clean" and then "flutter run "

Answer (score 0):

try this instead of column

```
ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 5,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index){
      return Text(quotes[index]);
        }
        ),
    );
```